# Как узнать настоящий индекс в строке, после которого стоит курсор, если используются emoji?

Tags: ios, swift

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда из-за использования emoji позиция курсора смещается на одну позицию. К примеру, если написать "текст", то если курсор в конце слова, то его позиция будет 5, но если после этого слова сразу поставить смайлик, то курсор за смайликом уже будет иметь позицию 7, хотя по логике должно было бы быть 6.

Я понимаю, что это связано с тем, что для emoji используется больше бит и из-за этого происходит смещение позиции. Но как тогда узнать реальную позицию курсора?

Если работать с простым текстом, то я просто из позиции курсора вычитал 1 и получал индекс символа после, которого стоит курсор (ну за исключением случая, когда курсор стоит в самом начале текста и его позиция 0). Но если использовать emoji такая методика не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я долго копался и нашёл решение. Небольшая функция, которая конвертирует оригинальную позицию курсора в аналог индекса (как в случае с позицией курсора при обычных однобитных символах).

```swift
func getRealCurPosition (text text: String, cur: Int) -> Int {
    if text != "" {
        var byteSumm = 0
        var i = 0
        for char in text.characters {
            byteSumm += String(char).utf16.count
            i += 1
            if byteSumm == cur {
                return i
            }
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

Принцип прост - создаётся счётчик для сложения сумм битов каждого знака. Проходим по массиву символов строки и находим размер в 16-битном режиме каждого символа строки и прибавляем этот размер к общему счётчику битов. Когда счётчик битов совпадёт с позицией курсора номер индекс этого символа и будет номер символа, после которого стоит курсор.